# mongoDB query to pass from string to integer and then sum

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have these fields:

```
_id: {
    contents: [{
        duration: "4",
        startDate : "2020-10-14",
    }, {
        duration: "15",
        startDate : "2020-11-17",
    }], 

}
```

And I need to find the contents that will expire in the next 10 days.
This is the logic I have to follow:

```
db.collection.find() 
    If duration > 10 =>  
        If ((duration - 10) + startDate) ==== today
```

But I can't transform the duration or startDate into number, or even how to do the conditional properly

Answer (score 0):

So for this ive made a collection in my mongo local that has a field that has numbers in it like the below image

[image]

Now to find sum of durations that are greater that 2....

[image]

Now as u see above the trick is to treat the comparator as a string as well.
Lemme attach a node snippet with mongoose as well

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/my_database';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
var db = mongoose.connection;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SomeModelSchema = new Schema({
    duration: String
});

var SomeModel = mongoose.model('SomeModel', SomeModelSchema );

SomeModel.aggregate([{ $match: {duration: { $gt : "2" }}},{ $group: { _id : null, sum: { $sum: {$toDouble: "$duration" }} } }], function(err, data){
    console.log(data)
});
  
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry that I wasn't specific enought. The problem consist on find all the contents that are going to expire in the next 10 days with the actual date. 
I tried to copy this part of your code: ```sum: { $sum: {$toDouble: "$duration" }}```
But is not detecting it, I can do ```"contents.duration": { $gt: "10" }```, but can't do it with only duration.
I'm going to edit my text to be more specific in the introduction

Comment: So in that case find just the items that fit the 'greater than 10' condition and use node logic to filter further from the array.

Comment: I did that, but the problem is that the array brings content from years ago and it becomes an array too big to handle

Answer (score 0):

Strings can not take advantages of numbers operations with indexes. If the table is too big that could end up with a very slow query.

Question 1: why are that fields inserted as string (just curious)
Question 2: why not update all to add a new field 'expiration' with exactly the moment (date or Unix time). That way is easy for the database find those records.

Comment: In addition to make your queries (and live! xD) easie, you could also set a Time To Live (TTL) index over that date field and mongo will delete the expired documents by itself.
I'll recomend you to update your data structure

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Q1: The fields are inserted as strings in case in the future someone needs to change from int to UUIDs for example
Q2: That is a good idea, but for the moment I can't do that I have to do it by query.

I have updated the story so you can have a better idea of what I'm doing